# Refreshing app on pressing back

Tags: android, android-activity

I have allowed the user to change languages. The language change is made on its own activity. When the user presses the back button, I want all the text to switch to the chosen language.

I'm using something like the following..

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (language.equals("en"))
        txTitle.setText("TITLE");
    else
        txTitle.setText("TITEL");

    super.onResume();
}
```

It doesn't refresh the page on pressing back.

Comment: How do I restart an activity upon pressing the back button? I thought the back button refreshes it?

Comment: If you want to restart activity on back button event then you have to override it

Comment: there must be some mistake, otherwise onResume should be invoked.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm an idiot. The `language` part was taken from preferences, but I was loading `language` during the `onCreate()` not `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go back to your previous activity, `onRestart()` event will be fired so you can call `onCreate()` method from within `onRestart()` to re-create your activity which I believe will change the language of your app.

Comment: Thanks, `onRestart()` is more precise than the `onResume()` I used here.

Comment: @Muz: When you take off one activity from the stack frame and go back to the previous one, `onRestart()` is called not `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (language.equals("en"))
      txTitle.setText("TITLE");
   else
     txTitle.setText("TITEL");      
}
```

But not a good way to do it, cause you wont be able to go to the previous activity.
Why not saving the language in SharedPreferences and load it on onCreate().

Comment: Ahh.. that was the problem. I *was* saving the language in SharedPreferences and loading it on `onCreate()`, but then the language wouldn't be loaded when the activity was resumed. Solution was to load the language in `onResume()`.

Comment: You should have posted your onCreate() method. Something definitely wrong there, then. Alternative is onRestart().

Answer (score 0):

@Muz
when you press back button, it does not call `onCreate()` function. So, you should add your necessary code part on `onResume()`.

Comment: It won't call `onResume()` either. It will call `onRestart()`. `onResume()` will be called after `onRestart()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity you can call:

```
Intent selectLanguage = new Intent("your_activity.this", 
                                   Your_secund_Activity.class);

startActivityForResult(selectLanguage, languageRequestCode);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==languageRequestCode) {
        //Your selected language number will be resultCode    
        //refresh methods
    }
}

//in the secund activity:

@Owerride
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setResult(selectedLanguageNumber);
}

@Owerride
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    setResult(selectedLanguageNumber);
}

@Owerride
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    setResult(selectedLanguageNumber);
}
```